# To open Vim in specific ":" mode from terminal

Tags: vim, text-editor

I use Vim in inspecting data. 
I would like to start Vim in specific ":" mode, for instance processing binary data in Terminal:

```
xxd -ps r328_0000.raw > /tmp/1 && vim /tmp/1 :%s/ffff//gn
                                            |
                                            ?
```

How can you start Vim in the ":"-mode in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the -c option (or just +) like this:

```
vim -c "%s/ffff//gn"
vim +"%s/ffff//gn"
```

From the manpage:

```
+{command}

-c {command}
           {command}  will  be  executed after the first file has been
           read.  {command} is interpreted as an Ex command.   If  the
           {command}  contains  spaces  it  must be enclosed in double
           quotes (this depends on the shell that is used).   Example:
           Vim "+set si" main.c
           Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.
```

Comment: I think `+"%s..."` is the better answer to the question.